# PHP - Having Issue with SQL Syntax in my PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First of all I do know, what this kind of error is already discussed numerious time in StackOVerflow, but non of these solutions in here works for me.

Secondly, here is the error message I'm geting: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE parking_time LIKE '%8%'' at line 1`

This is my code snippet:

```
$result = mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT( parking_time ) AS 'Amount', SUM( sum ) AS 'Sum'
    FROM parking_info
    GROUP BY MONTH( parking_time ) , YEAR( parking_time )
    ".$where."
    ") or die(mysql_error());
```

And this is how my DB looks like:

[image: DB fields]

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT COUNT( parking_time ) AS 'Amount', SUM( sum ) AS 'Sum'
FROM parking_info
GROUP BY MONTH( parking_time ) , YEAR( parking_time )
```

I don't know what the error is trying say to me, because I didn't see this line " WHERE parking_time LIKE '%8%'' at line 1 ".

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHERE` should come before `GROUP BY`.

In your query, you apparently add a where clause after group by:

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT( parking_time ) AS 'Amount', SUM( sum ) AS 'Sum'
FROM parking_info
GROUP BY MONTH( parking_time ) , YEAR( parking_time )
".$where."
") or die(mysql_error());
```

It looks like the `WHERE` clause is in the variable `$where`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two things : 
1. In your code snippet you have **$where** variable, you need to check from where does it come from and what the value it is having.
2. Also **group_by** should come after **where**